# Heap corruption error with delete []

Tags: c++, c++11, mfc, cstring, heap-corruption

So I'm a pretty big new at C++, so I'm sure this is a relatively simple problem, but I have a legacy C++ app I'm trying to trace a heap corruption problem and have traced it to this function:

```
void LTrimZeros(CString *pstr)
{
    char *psz1;
    char *psz2;

    if ( pstr->GetLength() == 0 )
        return;


    psz1 = new char[pstr->GetLength() + 1];
    psz2 = psz1;

    strcpy_s( psz2, strlen(psz2), (const char *) *pstr );

    while ( *psz2 == '0' )
    {
        psz2++;
    }

    *pstr = psz2;

    delete [] psz1;

    return;
}
```

When it tries to delete `psz1` it throws a heap corruption error.  Again I am pretty new to C++, so I didn't want to try to fix this and accidentally introduce a memory leak, so I thought I'd ask the experts.  Alternative solutions of the same function are also fine, as this app was written in like c++4 originally, but now is upgraded to c++11 (Also a brief explanation of why this causes heap corruption would help a lot).

Comment: Is that production code then?

Comment: Use `std::string` period! Get rid of that all pointer mumble jumble.

Comment: In the whilte loop, is it *psz2 == '0' ? or you mean *psz2 == '\0'

Comment: `psz1` is never used, `psz2` assigns itself to `psz1`. Have you checked that `GetLength()` returns an size that is valid? What about `strlen`? There is no way that will work properly. You already know the size so why not use `pstr->GetLength() + 1` as your length?

Comment: Yes it is production code, this app predates std::string I believe it would be a lot of work to replace it all, it is removing 0's not looking for a null terminator, and yes GetLength is returning the proper value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen(psz2)` is reading uninitialised memory so may read beyond the end of your array.  This means that the length you pass to `strcpy_s` will be unpredictable and may result in you writing beyond the end of the memory allocated for `psz1`.

Assuming the end of your function is valid (I'm not sufficiently familiar with [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to say for sure), you could simply change your `strcpy_s` line to

```
strcpy_s( psz2, pstr->GetLength() + 1, (const char *) *pstr );
```

You may run into problems here with win32 string handling functions that switch between 8 and 16-bit characters depending on the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` defines.  I agree with Alok Save and others that switching to using `std::string` would be clearer and simpler.

Comment: How about `*pstr = psz2;`?  Does `CString` support that? Nah.

Comment: @trojanfoe, Captain Oblivious I hadn't got that far through the function.  I'll reword my answer accordingly.

Comment: `psz2 = psz1;` doesn't that mean that `psz2` points to `psz1` which was just `new`ed up?

Comment: @TonyTheLion The whole method is pointless.  What's it trying to do?

Comment: @trojanfoe CString's `operator=()` takes a LPCSTR as input so `*pstr = psz2;` should be ok

Comment: Yeah this seems to fix the problem, Thanks!  @trojanfoe I'm pretty sure the method is just taking in a CString and pulling off any 0's it may have in front of it.

Comment: I'd love to switch it to std::string, but we're talking 20k+ lines of code that is all using CStrings throughout.  I'd sooner just rewrite the app in C#.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia But by definition a C-string is a NUL-terminated string of chars; do we know if CString holds a separate length instance variable?  It could just use the same logic (i.e. when you call `GetLength()` it does a `strlen()`).  If that's the case then there won't be any leading zeros...

Comment: @trojanfoe It's looking for leading 0's not leading null terminators?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Hehe, oops so it is :)

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

```
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
```

Here, in your code, you are calling `strlen` on an uninitialized array, you need to fix it (pass the **maximum number of elements the destination buffer can store**):

```
strcpy_s( psz2, strlen(psz2), (const char *) *pstr );
```

Comment: Didn't you just copy the bug to pass strlen(psz2) as length parameter to strcpy_s()?

Comment: Yes, I am showing exact line with the bug here, not showing a bug fix (left as an exercise to the reader - should be easy, really).